# Use 1 script on multiple sheets and each new sheet adds a new column to the archive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sorry if the title sounds a bit weird, here's my situation:

I have a script to take the quantity of each column at the end of the week and add the information for archival purposes to an Archive sheet, but I have no way to format the output and it only runs through a single sheet. In the end there's going to be ~10 sheets that all have to have data archived end of the week every week. Below is the code I found that works well for one sheet "E2 - Electrical" but I plan to have about 9 more sheets, and I dont really think having this script run 10 times for 10 different sheets to 10 different Archive sheets is the best way to do it? I also would really like if it archived as a column, since it's a lot of items to archive each sheet.

```
var rangeToLog = 'E2 - Electrical!E2:E81';
var sheetToLogTo = 'Archive';

function appendValuesToArchiveSheet() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var valuesToLog = ss.getRange(rangeToLog).getValues();
  var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToLogTo);
  if (!logSheet) {
    logSheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetToLogTo);
    logSheet.appendRow(['Date time']);
  }
  var rowToAppend = [new Date()].concat(
    valuesToLog.reduce(function concatArrays_(left, right) {
      var arrayContainsData = right.some(function isNonBlanky_(element, index, array) {
        return element !== null && element !== undefined && element !== '';
      });
      return arrayContainsData ? left.concat(right) : left;
    })
  );
  logSheet.appendRow(rowToAppend);
}
```

The script works well but it's going to get very clunky very fast for my needs.

Edit: Sample sheet here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MGBAiLEIJYhckuq0kK61JkFyM_ys5zVX8E5h3ulBPl4/edit#gid=0

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By the way, what does `I also would really like if it archived as a column, since it's a lot of items to archive each sheet.` mean?

Comment: Hi and welcome. `var rangeToLog = 'E2 - Electrical!E2:E81';` this is your problem. You need to have one variable for the "range", say `var range = "E2:E81"`, and another variable (an array) for all the sheets on which you want to run this. For example, `var sheetnames = ["E2 - Electrical", "E3 - Engineering", "E4 - Service"]`. Then loop though "sheetnames", running your archiving code (for each sheet) inside the loop.

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry, I know it's kind of hard to understand. Basically I'm trying to archive the movement of mechanical parts and that sort of thing from "carts" around the shop. Each cart is labelled something specific like "E2 - Electrical" but most are something along the lines of "Cart 1", "Cart 2". Each of these "carts" will be a separate tab in my spreadsheet, I want a script at the end of the week to run through each tab, gather all the data that's been input over said week, and archive it long term in a tab labelled "Archive" so data analysis can be performed on it for trends.

Comment: @Tanaike In terms of the columns, right now my script that I posted takes the info I want and copies it to the Archive tab, but it's in rows, the columns saved for the date of the script running (so this week it'll be labelled 2/24/23) and each column is a single item, and every cart has anywhere from about 50-100 parts, that's a lot of separate rows and requires you to scroll side-to-side to see all the data, which is really tedious. I want it to instead post the data in a single column or 2 columns so everything can be seen much easier. Right now the E2 cart lists items from column A to CC.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike Every day a user will enter in new information using checkboxes, those checkboxes are taken to another sheet and put together to give a total that adds up over the week, the boxes reset each day and the process is done again until the end of the week. At the end of the week, I want a script to take the data that has been added up over the week and copy it to the Archive sheet for archiving. Its sort of a way to see trends over long periods for analysis, consider it a way to potentially start a forecast.

Comment: @Tedinoz I gave this a shot but i'm not that familiar with coding so it didnt seem to work at all.

Comment: "i'm not that familiar with coding" Oh. that's not the impression that one gets from your existing code. That was developed by someone else, yes?It has some quite sophisticated methods. Anyway, please include anything that you've tried - it's always better to help someone solve their problem, than to solve it for them.

Comment: @Tedinoz Right, it's not my code, I wish I was that good lol, managed to find it online that seems to work with what I need to a degree. I haven't really tried anything because idk what I'm doing in the first place :(

Comment: OK. Everyone has to start somewhere. But there are issues that you aren't mentioning because, as you say, "ydk what you're doing in the first place". So you need to supply some sample data as well as an example of the Archive Sheet. Assume 1) there are only 2 sheets ("E2 - Electrical" and "E3 - Electrical" and 2) the range is only 3 rows ("E2:E4"). Please edit your question to supply some sample data for the range for **both** sheets, and then supply an example of the Archive sheet as it should look after processing.

Comment: @daronmal I'll give you an idea what I am getting at. First, I was surprised that the Archive data was transposed and I want to check that this is intentional; second, how do you propose to distinguish the data between one sheet and another. The sheet name seems like an obvious choice, but where/which column, and perhaps that is NOT what you intend. You also mentioned formatting the output but we don't what sort of data it is, nor the nature of the formatting.